# How do selection committees ensure that they won't steal an applicant's ideas as presented in his/her research statement?

Tags: application, plagiarism, research-statement

Academic job applications usually require the submission of a research statement, which describes not only the applicant's research experience, but also future direction of their work. As such, it may contain some novel ideas.

Considering that a research statement is not a publication, and therefore, can't be cited, how does a selection committee ensure that nothing in an applicant's research statement (especially those of unsuccessful applicants) will be stolen by anyone in the selection committee who reads it?

I mean, since the applicant's submitted documents are probably only known to the selection committee and the applicant him/herself, isn't it easy for anyone in the committee to copy those ideas without being found out?

A related question, if a member in the committee identifies an interesting and promising idea of an unsuccessful applicant, and is keen to pursue the idea, what should the committee member do? How do you give credit to the unsuccessful applicant when the research statement is the only document where the idea is described?

To be clear, my concern is more on the committee, not how I can prevent the committee from stealing my idea. One day I might be sitting as a selection committee member myself, and I'd like to know what I should do in this situation.

This question is related to [Research statement ideas got used by interviewing committee](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/), but looking from the perspective of the committee.

Comment: Isn't it like most ethical issues in academia?  Nothing prevents a person from breaking the rules, but there would be dire consequences if they were found out.

Comment: @Nate: Yes, I think so.  Moreover, like most of these issues: if we actually trust academics to behave ethically, the system works great.  If we don't, then it is very difficult to imagine how to modify it so as to correct for this unethical behavior.

Comment: Maybe my view of academia is too rosy, but assuming that a selection committee will first reject you and then steal your excellent ideas seems unlikely enough that no specific counter-measures are necessary.

Comment: More generally, I think many people spend *way* too much time worrying who might all steal their ideas (reviewers, advisors, colleagues, selection committees, etc). In the end, if you never tell anybody about your research, how will you ever get feedback or collaborations?

Comment: I think people in this site don't pay proper attention to this kind of "security problems".  Bank and email accounts, houses, cars and laptops are well protected with keys and passwords, but a successful track in publications can lead to think that everything is "rosy" (as @xLeitix pointed). E.g. I've seen two organizations applying for funding for a project, failing and then one of the organizations applying again (without the other, same project) for funding at a different place. I've seen many more examples and I'm sure all who have been long enough in academia have seen their own share.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark *" if we actually trust academics to behave ethically, the system works great"* you mean that the system works great *in our imagination*, right?

Comment: _I've seen two organizations applying for funding for a project, failing and then one of the organizations applying again (without the other, same project) for funding at a different place._ — I'm not sure this is the best example. I've seen a similar situation, where there was nothing unethical going on at all. One of the organizations just decided not to pursue the project further.

Comment: @JeffE that could be the case, but it wasn't, the organization that was left aside was mostly responsible for the authorship of the proposal and was left aside with no notice or question. I'm sure there are many villages in the world were you can leave your house open and trust on ethics, but that doesn't make "ethics" a good security system. Anything that is not public and transparent is a potential source of corruption (academia, politics…) and it *will* be an actual source of corruption in some cases (due to statistics). Academia could and should be more transparent, that'd only be good.

Comment: @Trylks: I have never had anyone steal my ideas, and I am having trouble thinking of anyone that I know personally in my field who had their ideas stolen.  So I don't think it's my imagination that academics behave ethically in this matter the overwhelming majority of the time.  It may be my delusion, or a limitation of my own experience, but I tend to agree with xLeitix that people (especially, some poeple on this site) seem overly concerned that this will happen.

Comment: But I agree completely with (and practice) the remedy in your answer: if you make your work very public, then any theft would also be public.  You can in the full light of day steal someone's wallet, but I don't see how you can successfully steal someone's ideas in a similarly well-lighted situation.  You might be able to publish them, but that does not in itself gain you credit in the community.  In a functional academic community (such exist outside of my imagination) you will in fact lose substantial credit in the long run by doing this, which deters most people who have something to lose.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think the concern is normal, as leaving the house open. I'm aware there are villages where this is the norm, but I'd not be surprised if newcomers were puzzled by this practice. The point is: security cameras (publishing) work better than locks (keeping private), so I'd say that should be the common advice instead of simply "don't worry", because, not to worry, a "camera" (usually not stated) would be the way to go...

Comment: @NateEldredge, in the case of research statement, how to find out?

Answer (score 10):

Academics are presented with confidential material all the time. We review manuscripts and grants and we are expected to not steal those ideas. A research statement is very similar to a grant proposal. When we are given applications to review we are reminded that they are confidential and should not be circulated. This is the same as when reviewing a grant. While many funding agencies and publishers have clear statements that reviewers must agree to, departments generally do not produce such guidelines. That said, a department would likely come down very hard on an individual who did not respect the confidentiality of an applicant.

With that out of the way, it is often that a reviewer has similar ideas as an applicant. On the face of it, it may appear that the reviewer has stolen the idea from a proposal, when in fact it was an independent idea that the reviewer had already had. One question is should reviewers decline to review based on a conflict of interest when the proposed work is similar to their current/future work. In my opinion, they should not since they are in the best position to review the work and the similarity is likely the reason they have been asked to review. This then does leave the burden on the reviewers to be able to document that the research agenda is in fact their own and not stolen from the confidential proposal.

The final issue is to document anything that is unique to your proposal. Saying you want to study topic X does not make it yours. Saying you want to study topic X with method Y, isn't much better. If the proposal says I want to study topic X with novel method Y because of reason Z, then the linking of X, Y, and Z might be important. If you document this, then at least if someone studies X with Y, you can get the credit for coming up with the brilliant idea of using method Y on problem X. In some ways realising that problem X can be solved with method Y is more important than actually solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you mind explaining more what you mean by documenting?

Comment: Also, do you mind elaborating more on "department would likely come down very hard on an individual who did not respect the confidentiality of an applicant"? How to find out?

Answer (score 5):

Best way to prevent ideas from being stolen (IMHO): write them up and make them public. You don't need to publish them in a top journal or conference, simply write them up (as the research statement is probably already written) and put them on arxiv, figshare or whatever suits you (I think we need a list for these services). Short and simple.

I was told once that one difference between science and engineering is exactly that. The engineer will have an idea and protect it by not telling anybody and *patenting* it. The scientist will protect the idea (the authorship of the idea) by *publishing* it and telling everybody. I don't fully agree due to the characteristics of software engineering, open source and copyright, but I think it serves to illustrate the point.

Sure publishing on a journal or conference requires telling some people before that (the reviewers) and not all ideas are suitable to be published in such places (any reputed venue will reject most of the submissions, there are usually associated costs, etc.) There is the risk of reviewers stealing some ideas (not in a completely straightforward way, to abide the rules) and I think the main reason why there is arxiv is exactly that.

Publishing online is free and immediate. It won't give you much impact and it won't count for some metrics, but it will provide testimony that you had that idea at that time (even if more people could have had the same idea in an independent way, as @StrongBad pointed). Then you should find a venue that accepts what you already published in this manner, not all venues will do so and depending on your area most venues may reject such papers, but the fact that most people do something doesn't mean that thing is right.

Finally, the problem (IMHO) is that we are giving great value to something as intangible as ideas, because they are important and have great impact on the progress of society and the career of those who are responsible for those ideas. However, as a society, we are not really prepared to handle intangible things properly, there are attempts to improve that, but all of them are still falling short in some aspects.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that arXiv is there to prevent reviewers from stealing ideas?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, but it seems perfectly suited for that.

Comment: And how did you get from that to thinking that this was the main purpose?

Comment: It's an archive of pre-prints, if printed papers can be accessed (specially with the current convergence towards open access, which should have been the norm from the start) what is the point of pre-prints? Pre-print leads to pre-edition, pre-reviewer, etc. Additionally, the name, an archive evokes something to keep the proofs (as when the police archives a case), openness is better evoked by portals, gates, indexes, etc. The name suggests it's not for accessing but keeping papers, actually "pre-papers". What other purpose (main or not) could it possibly have?

Comment: It has the purpose of making research papers available to the entire research community as soon as they are ready and without being behind any paywalls. Without the arXiv, papers in math, for example, would end up not being available until usually at least six months later (sometimes much longer). Sure, it also serves as a means to establish precedent, but that is in no way the main contribution of it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft even if it isn't the main contribution of it, it seems to be the main and possibly best suited way to achieve that, AFAIK.

Comment: I am not disputing that the best way to establish precedent is using the arXiv. I am just saying that this is a positive side effect of the main purpose of the arXiv, rather than actually the main purpose (as a side note, I think that if I saw a research statement on the arXiv, I would most likely consider the person who put it there overly paranoid).

Comment: I agree other services (e.g. figshare) may be better suited for anything besides papers. Even a blogging platform could be nice if there were trustworthy time-stamped diffs (at least as posts here…), unfortunately I couldn't find any. WRT paranoia, if this is something that can award a job, I think it can be plagiarized. How could that be detected if it is not public? Not too long ago a political party [plagiarized ](http://goo.gl/fsG4xk) the program of another party in the EU elections… If that happens for stuff that is public, what could happen for everything that is not? I don't wanna know.

Comment: Publishing on the arXiv won't protect the research idea. People can still come up with similar ideas, it if they claim that they had not seen your work, there is no responsibility for them to even mention your work.

Comment: I agree with @Trylks and a great service for this is likely ResearchGate, as it generates DOIs for documents.